# CSV duplicate/copy first row to a table

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I've created an automated job using UC4 where the job is inserting data from one CSV file example.csv to a table example_table. The job is working fine and it is copying all the data from example.csv to example_table except the first row (i.e., header row that contains the name of columns).

I want to insert this first row (name of columns) of example.csv to example_table. Directly copying the first row and pasting it below is not working. I cannot make any changes to example.csv. Doing research on the internet was not much helpful, so I'm asking here. Is there any bash or shell command to insert the header row to example.csv?

example.csv is looking like this:

```
A, B, C
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

example_table is looking like this:

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

Required/expected example_table is:

```
A, B, C
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

Comment: what commands you have tried to do this ? have you tried using `cat example.csv | column -t` ?

Comment: On which operating system are you running? The `cmd` tag is for Microsoft Windows cmd.exe issues. The `bash` and `shell` tags are usually not Windows, but can be. Please clarify.

Comment: Removed `cmd` tag. Not running on Windows.

Comment: @suleiman `cat` command did not work.

Comment: how did `cat`not work, you don't have rights to read that file ? Please clarify what you have tried and add it to your post.

Answer (score 2):

If i got your requirement correctly

1. Get header
2. Combine with cat into std output using ()
3. Write to file

```
echo "A, B, C" > example.csv
echo "1, 2, 3" >> example.csv
echo "4, 5, 6" >> example.csv

echo "1, 2, 3" > example_table.csv
echo "4, 5, 6" >> example_table.csv

(head -1 example.csv ; cat example_table.csv) > example_table_with_header.csv;
```

[image]